# How to get which object began touch in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uitouch

I have one view in iPhone application. In that view i added two UIImageView lets say img_view1, img_view2. Now i put touch event on that view as following.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     // Some code are here
}
```

how do i can get which image view began to touch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint pt = [touch locationInView:self];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(img_view1.frame, pt)
{
    NSLog(@"Image View 1 touched");
}
```

etc.

Comment: error: Semantic Issue: Passing 'UIImageView *' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect')

Answer (score 0):

Make your image view user interaction enabled in the xib (or through the code if you are adding it programmatically) and use the UIResponder methods touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded etc to detect the touch on the image view:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if ([touch view] == yourImageView)
{
        //add your code for image touch here 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if (touch.view==imageView1) { 
  // do something
}
else if (touch.view==imageView2) { 
  // do something else
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        if(touch.view == img_view1)
        {
    }
    else if(touch.view == img_view2)
        {
    }
}
```